# Is it possible to implement custom add ons for Google Slides?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, add-on

Is it possible to implement custom add ons for Google Slides? 
I need to be able to insert custom content into presentation (e.g. google map of a specified location as an image, etc).

The official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/) mentions only Docs, Sheets and Forms.

Comment: It seems it's not possible. Neither the documentation mentions it nor the application contains a script editor.